# Ajuda para configurar WAMP Server

Tags: php, wampserver

Estou com um problema no WAMP server, onde não consigo acessar meu projeto pelo **LocalHost** quando clico diretamente no nome do projeto, apenas se digitar **"localhost/nome_do_projeto"**.

Alguém tem alguma dica para poder configurar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro da pasta WWW do wamp, você vai encontrar um arquivo chamado índex.php, abra-o.

Na linha 338 você vai encontrar o seguinte

```
$projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.($suppress_localhost ? '//' : '').$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
```

Se não achar pesquisa por $projectContents no editor de sua preferencia para você achar a linha certa, pois dependendo da versão pode alterar a linha.

Para acertarmos esse problema devemos adicionar a frente de HTTP:// a palavra localhost, pois essa linha é a responsável por montar a url no navegador, pois da maneira que está o wamp monta a url somente com o nome do seu projeto por exemplo,  sendo que desta forma não abrirá nosso arquivo, mostrando erro de pagina inexistente.

Então para solucionarmos esse problema devemos deixar essa linha dessa forma:

```
$projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.($suppress_localhost ? '//localhost/' : '').$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
```

Prontinho, seu localhost já deverá estar acessando seus trabalhos pelo clique na pasta.

Agora na pasta wamp/scripts/ temos um arquivo chamado refresh.php, abra-o e na linha 651 você irá encontrar o seguinte comando:

```
$myreplacesubmenuProjects .= 'Type: item; Caption: "'.$projectContents[$i].'"; Action: run; FileName: "'.$c_navigator.'"; Parameters: "// '.$projectContents[$i].'/"; Glyph: 5';
```

Para corrigir, devemos fazer o mesmo à frente de // desta maneira:

```
$myreplacesubmenuProjects .= 'Type: item; Caption: "'.$projectContents[$i].'"; Action: run; FileName: "'.$c_navigator.'"; Parameters: "//localhost/'.$projectContents[$i].'/"; Glyph: 5 ';
```

Reinicie os serviços do wamp só por garantia e, se tudo ocorrer bem, seus projetos poderão ser acessados através do localhost.

Comment: Qual o problema que esta dando quando tu tenta acessar o projeto?

Comment: Tava um pouco diferente mas consegui. Deu certinho. Obrigado

Comment: Precisando estamos aqui :D